# Which Web Server To Setup In University Project Center

Tags: webserver

We want to setup and configure a web server for our project center in our university and we want to supply a web server for student web applications based on Php, Python and also Asp.Net.

Is there anyway to supply a server for all these 3 different platforms ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS (ie. a Windows server) can run all 3.

ASP.NET can't be run on anything but Windows, to my knowledge, so that's your limiting factor.

Comment: We are thinking to use Mono for our asp.net projects. Isn't it a solution for that ?

Comment: @Kubi - I actually wasn't aware that it was an option.  Still, despite the massive respect for the mono project and its developers I have, they've started out many years behind and are working to catch up.  The fact remains, they are behind.  They have a brief summary of current support at http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET.  I'd suggest you aren't doing your students any favors by keeping them off the bleeding edge.

Answer (score 2):

if you really need asp, then i think you're limited to IIS on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, I would look at setting up a Windows Server, then look at a control panel such as "Plesk" to help you with management/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use Apache and [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) to serve up ASP.NET applications with Mono, although I've never used this approach myself.